How to cut down on argument redundancy in purrr::map
Map statements are just awesome, but their inputs often feel needlessly redundant. For example, in the block below, it seems silly to have to re-list the variables I've already requested from the tibble. In short, I wish I could just put \() for the anonymous functions. Anyone have a way to cut down the redundancy? Of course, I could do this task below with mutate, but I'm just trying to demonstrate what I'm looking for.
library(tidyverse)

mtcars |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(
    test = pmap_chr(
      .l = list(mpg,cyl),
      .f = \(mpg,cyl){ #Ahhhh! So redundant!!!
        str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}")
      }
    )
  )


PS: "~" is no longer best practice, even though that helps me.
PPS: This is not an official part of the question since it is opinion-based, but do you have a preference for using map in mutate vs on a list directly? I've found using them with mutate to be more organized and require less setup, but I've always wondered if this was a good idea. I don't see it as often as people just setting up lists and feeding them into purrr::map

I think you need to come up with a better example because as you say you can just do mutate(test = str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}")) and it's going to be hard to do better than that. If you need to use pmap_chr() and you want to avoid typing, then in your example you can replace the function with \(...) str_glue("{..1}_{..2}") but frankly I think the cost in readability is much greater than the saving of a few keystrokes.

Why do you say ~ is no longer "best practice"? Is there some plan to deprecate that? It's a part of purrr and in this case you could just use .f = ~str_glue("{.x}_{.y}"). The \() {} functions are just a new base R syntax. I haven't heard any plans for the tidyverse to eliminate mapper functions.

@MrFlick, current tidyverse recommendation is to switch to using \(x) for lambda functions instead of ~ .x. See e.g. ?map: "Only recommended if you require backward compatibility with older versions of R." Also see note 2 here. Don't think there is a plan for deprecation, just a recommendation to switch over.

@Axeman Thanks for the references. If the goal is to reduce code, one is still better off with purrr mappers. I don't think base R syntax will ever get that terse. It's better to be explicit so everything works as expected and there are fewer "magic" surprises. If they aren't deprecated it doesn't seem like much of a risk to me.

Sounds like maybe I should just submit this as a request on github :)! Thanks for your thoughts. Wanted to makes sure it wasn't just me (unless of course someone comes along and figures it out).

So what exactly are you going to request? Do you want changes to the tidyverse or the base R syntax?

Tidyverse -- option to leave out the arguments in \() since they are already clear from .l = list(mpg,cyl), however they want to implement that. Seeing as they are moving away from ~, I think there is a good chance they already decided against this for a reason not yet clear to me. It's not too bad here, but I often use many variables, and it can look really ugly...and make it hard to manage code/make edits if adding or removing one. I often forget to do it in one and not the other

@Aegis note that you can use \(x, y) str_glue("{x}_{y}") instead of giving the actual variable names.

As pointed out in the comments we do not actually need pmap_* here but let us say for purposes of answering the question that we must use it.
Then we can use the formula representing a function ~ with(list(...) ..whatever..) to avoid repeating the arguments while allowing us to refer to the arguments by name. In this code we have used dot (.) for brevity but if we were using |> or if the mutate were in a group_by use the more verbose pick(everything()) instead.
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>%
  mutate(test = pmap(., ~ with(list(...), str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}"))))
##                mpg cyl disp   test
## Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160   21_6
## Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160   21_6
## Datsun 710    22.8   4  108 22.8_4

If it were ok to use str_glue_data we could simplify it slightly.
mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>%
  mutate(test = pmap(., ~ str_glue_data(list(...), "{mpg}_{cyl}")))

Here is a different example to show that with/list works in other situations too:
dat <- data.frame(a = 11:13, b = 21:23, c = 1:3)
dat %>%
  mutate(p.value = pmap_dbl(., ~ with(list(...), prop.test(a, b)$p.value)))
##    a  b c   p.value
## 1 11 21 1 1.0000000
## 2 12 22 2 0.8311704
## 3 13 23 3 0.6766573

auxfun
We define a short utility function which generates the auxiliary function to be used in pmap_*
auxfun <- function(e) {
  .s <- substitute(e)
  function(...) eval(.s, list(...))
}

mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>%
  mutate(test = pmap_chr(., auxfun( str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}") ) ) )

.by
It should be pointed out that simply using the mutate argument .by= is simpler and more compact.
For the .by= argument we can use any unique column or set of columns . If there are no duplicate rows we can use everything(). If there might be duplicate rows create a column of unique values first using mutate(row = row_number()) and then use .by = row .
In the first example below we don't actually need .by= but, as discussed at the beginning, to address the question which assumes the need for evaluating an expression separately for each row we include it.
mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>%
  mutate(test = str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}"), .by = everything())

dat %>%
  mutate(p.value = prop.test(a, b)$p.value, .by = c)


Wow, super cool, I've never seen it done that way! Super succinct. As mentioned in my post and in the reasoning from others in the comments, I'm trying to avoid a solution with ~.

The same solution works with \(...) in place of ~ but of course ~ is more compact.

Wow, nice solution! Admittedly, I was hoping that we could do this without introducing base R (with), however I never specified that and this does answer the question well. I will mark it as such. Thanks!

You can use reframe if you unlist it afterwards but with is shorter.  mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>% mutate(test = pmap_chr(., ~ reframe(tibble(...), str_glue("{mpg}_{cyl}"))[[1]]))

Sorry, I thought I had accepted the answer. I just did that now.
